# PyLint 1.0.0 with PyDev 2.8.2

Tags: pydev, pylint

Having upgraded pylint and pydev on Eclipse/Windows I have two problems

1. I get a warning on EVERY line about trailing whitespace, although there is no trailing whitespace.
2. the description in the problems panel does not show the warning/error ID number anymore

is there some extra setup I need?

----update----

I have added ignore-C0303 to get rid of whitespace warnings, and added
msg-template={msg_id}:{line:3d},{column}: {obj}: {msg}
to get the ID's back.
The only problem I have left is 
ignored-argument-names=_.*
does not seem to work. I always get W0613 warnings for arguments starting with _
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trailing whitespace false positive under windows platform is described https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issue/55/ and resolved, though the fix has not been released yet.

For your other problem, W0613 is not impacted by the ignored-argument-names configuration, but by dummy-variables-rgx whose default has been changed in 1.0 to match only '_', not any identifier with leading underscore. This particular change/issue is discuted on https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issue/98/local-variables-with-leading-underscore.